# I can't find References section in my LaTeXed pdf file

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, endnotes

First, I exported my references list from EndNote X7 using 'BibTeX Export' and saved the text file as 'first_paper.bib'.
Then I included the following code into my TeX file.

```
\newpage
% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{first_paper}   % name your BibTeX data base
```

This code is included in the template TeX file provided by the journal and I only edited the database name to 'first_paper'. This 'first_paper.bib' file is located at the same folder as the TeX file.

I complied this code twice but I can't find References section in the final PDF file. What's wrong with this?

Comment: You have to run the external program `bibtex`. Your editor should have a button to do this. Do `pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex`

Comment: I got it! TeXWorks editor provides options to compile it by pdfLaTeX, BibTex and others. I complied bibtex twice and then pdflatex twice. What's the right order to do this and how many times I should run them?

Comment: See my edited comment above. You need only once. If you change the `bib` file or cite some new, run again.